# Node Express: How to request data and not a page

Tags: node.js, express, axios, fetch

I am learning Node.js. This is a very newbie question.

I want to fetch some data from my database via node.js server. I am using Axios and so my line of code looks like this. But it is just an ordinary fetch request.

const response = api.get("/");

But I do not retrieve the data with this. I retrieve a completely new page that looks like this.

[image: browser window with retrieved data]

It is an empty page with the data that I want to retrieve. But I do not need a new page. I need the data only. I want to store it in the RESPONSE variable. How can I do that?

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Perhaps I should watch a video on how to build a REST API?

Comment: What you see here is a JSON / Object you received from making the call to the API endpoint you are calling in your Axios request. It's now up to you to destruct the object and use the data that's in there.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a page. It is your browser's way of rendering the data of your response. You can use a JSON viewer plugin for your browser if you expect to see pretier data or use an HTTP client like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) to be sure that your API returns what you expect.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. You are right. It is not a page. It is just data render into the browser.

I want to save the data (it is an array with one object) into my the the CONST RESPONSE variable. Is there a way to do it? It must be, it just was not part of the node course that I did.

Comment: I probably should watch a tutorial on how to use React with Node.

Comment: Or I probably should google how to retrieve data from node.js.

Comment: I can help if you can provide me a piece of code so I can better understand the issue

Comment: Thanks a lot again. To share my code with you, I decided to create a simplified version of my app. And while I was working on it, I figured where was the problem.

My React was on port 3000. My Node was also on port 3000. And once I started my Node, it just rendered the data and not the React page. The system somehow prefers Node. Life is beautiful again. If not for you, I would not figure it out so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

So this was the problem.

My React was on port 3000. My Node was also on port 3000. When I started my React App, everything was fine and my browser displayed all pages perfectly well. But once I started my Node, it rendered data into the browser.

Just now I changed the Node port to 4000 and the problem is gone.

It seems like React and Node were competing here who is going to render the content into my browser. Node was prefered by my chrome browsers. Perhaps because I started it later.